# Position element according to body instead of the relative parent

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a div with position relative and two children using it and both have position absolute. And I need them. But I want to make another child inside the relative div and give it the position absolute. But now the problem is that I want some part of it to appear outside of the element. So how can I do it in CSS? Thanks in advance.[image: Example]

Reference to what I need is: [Example of what I need, check the search icon. How it is placed. I want that kind of thing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zruIr.png)

```
div {
   //Parent div
    position:relative;
}
div {
   //Child div
    position:absolute;
}
div {
   //Child div
    position:absolute;
   //This is an emoji
   //But I want this to appear half outside of the parent div,
   //i.e. on the border of the parent div
}
```

Comment: you have position:fxied for this

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. A question like this should come with more than just “what I want” and an image, to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the given example, section is the parent div  which is relative and rest 2 child, or you can have as many as you want, all are absolute, and image is out on border as you requested

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
img {max-width: 30px;}
section {border:15px solid #ccc; border-radius: 20px; height: 100px; position: relative;}
.child {position: absolute;}
.child1 {top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%);}
.childEmoji {top: 0; left:0; transform: translate(-50%,-50%);}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="child child1">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child childEmoji"><img src="https://images.macrumors.com/t/45wRHEDrpfO6dWOSqibLkzcZG-s=/800x0/filters:quality(90)/article-new/2017/11/crying-tears-of-joy-emoji-250x248.jpg"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: adjust the top left right and bottom properties as per your need

Answer (score 0):

Use vw or vh in your positioning. If you use for example: 50% it will get the width of the parent and then divide it by 2. If you use vw(width of page) or vh(height of page) it takes the width and height of the whole page. Should work for you. Remember your positioning is important as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Hey, but I asked for positioning the element on the border of the parent div. I guess there is nothing related to the width and height of the element. I want to display it half inside the border and half outside the border. I have added the image of what I need in the question. So, if you can help me in that then it would be great.